# Show custom directive in ng-repeate every 10th element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display banner after every tenth element in ngRepeat and change it depending on filters(currently I didn't implemented functionality for changing, but I listen for changing event). I've created following directive for banner:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('calendar')
        .directive('banner', banner);

    banner.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$compile', 'bannerService'];

    // Usage: <div data-banner=""></div>
    function banner($rootScope, $compile, bannerService) {
        var config = {},
            templates = [],
            bannerRowTemplate = '<div class="row"><div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">{0}</div></div></div>',
            bannerItemTemplate = '<div class="item {0}">{1}</div>';

        var directive = {
            scope: {
                item: '=banner'
            },
            link: link,
            priority: 100001,
            restrict: 'A'
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.item) {
                bannerService.getBannersConfig(receivedConfig);

                $rootScope.$on('FiltersChanged', function (event, originEvents, sortType) {
                    element.html(getBannersHtml()).show();
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        }

        function receivedConfig(data) {
            config = data.config;
            templates = data.banners;
        }

        function getBannersHtml() {
            var inner = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
                inner += bannerItemTemplate.format(i == 0 ? 'active' : '', templates[i]);
            }

            return bannerRowTemplate.format(inner);
        }
    }
  })();
```

I have this in my view:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="event in events | offset: (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage" data-repeat-finish="">
        <div eventtitle="event.title"></div>
        <div>{{event.date}}</div>

        <div data-banner="$index % 10 == 0"></div>
</div>
```

But directive does not render. Script executes, but directive inner html does not change. I also tried ng-if, ng-show instead of passing $index % 10 to directive.

Comment: So - data-banner will equal something for each iteration *except* the 10th 20th, etc.  What are you doing with that data? (Nothing, it appears).  What is the desired result?

Comment: Also, a jsFiddle - with event data - so we can actually see this working, and revise / tweak as appropriate - would be super helpful.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I was refactoring view to show only important things and accidantialy removed ==0. This is working if I add  <div data-banner="true"></div> anywhere outside the ngRepeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show or ng-if for this.
The difference between these two is that:

**ng-if** If false does not render the banner.

**ng-show** If false renders the banner and hides it.

Remove the item binding from your directive declaration

```
var directive = {
    link: link,
    priority: 100001,
    restrict: 'A'
};

return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    bannerService.getBannersConfig(receivedConfig);

    $rootScope.$on('FiltersChanged', function (event, originEvents, sortType) {
        element.html(getBannersHtml()).show();
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    });
}
```

Then call your directive like this

```
<div data-ng-show="$index % 10 == 0" data-banner></div>
```

Or like this

```
<div data-ng-if="$index % 10 == 0" data-banner></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as I mentioned above "I also tried ng-if, ng-show instead of passing $index % 10 to directive".
Additionally, even if I remove the condition, to make it appear for each event, it won't